# Modifying MySQL JDBC driver for audits?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there a way to monitor and intercept the JDBC traffic from inside the MySQL JDBC driver? If yes, what are some convenient points (eg: Filename, function name) in the [driver source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/connectorj/5.1/files) to put this logic?

We have a few secure server apps and need to monitor the traffic for reads to certain 'special' fields. If such a 'special' read is detected, we want to overwrite the contents.

FYI, we already have db permissions, views etc setup. This would be yet another monitoring mechanism (defence in depth) should there be a programming error in the higher layers.

Comment: In other words you need something like AOP logging mechanism across your database access methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this - http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/

site says

> P6Spy is a framework that enables database data to be seamlessly intercepted and manipulated with no code changes to existing application.